# Bash assignment with "let" fails with "/"

Tags: bash, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I'm using GNU bash, versión 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), and I wonder why a simple assignment statement gives a syntax error:

```
#/bin/bash

var1=/tmp       # This works
let var2=/tmp   # This fails with syntax error: Operand expected (error is "/tmp")
```

Does anybody know why? Thanks

Comment: `help let` should show you why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` is a shell builtin that is a another way to use the `$((..))` [Arithmetic Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) in bash. The assignment

```
let var2=/tmp
```

is treated by the shell as an arithmetic operation "division" with an incorrect quotient value. It is equivalent to doing.

```
var=$((/tmp))
```

Since there are incorrect number of operands, the parser has thrown the error that you are seeing. Note that `tmp` is still treated in a variable context by the shell. If the parser had identified the expression as valid, then `tmp` would have undergone variable expansion. Since it is not set before, it would have likely thrown a "division-by-zero" error.

For simple variable assignments just drop the `let` keyword and enclose the value field within "quotes"

```
var2="/tmp"
```

Answer (score 2):

`let` is used only for arithmetic operations, just as `(( ))`.

Therefore, the following lines are the same

```sh
a=$((60 * 60))
let a=(60*60)
((a = 60 * 60))
```

See the [manpage](https://ss64.com/bash/let.html).